# pass data to controller using javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-3

I have multiple data selected from checkbox bs table and i want to pass these data to the controller and redirect to another page. Below is the code which i have tried:

**View:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkedRows = [];

    $('#eventsTable').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
      checkedRows.push({dc_no: row.dc_no, name: row.customer_name});
      console.log(checkedRows);
      });

    $('#eventsTable').on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row) {
      $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
      if (value.id === row.id) {
          checkedRows.splice(index,1);
        }
      });
    console.log(checkedRows);
  });

    $("#add_cart").click(function() {
    $("#output").empty();
    $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
      $('#output').append($('<li></li>').text(value.dc_no + " | " + value.name ));
    });
  });
    </script>
```

Selected data is being listed by `$.each(checkedRows, function(index, value)`.So, how to pass value of **dc_no** and some other field to the controller.

Comment: You can send your data in json format using ajax.

Comment: I have already tried it but i want to redirect to another page. whereas by using ajax it send response to the same view after submitting data to the controller. and what i want is to redirect to another view with that data.

Comment: You can use Window.location.href to redirect to a desired page after ajax finish.

Comment: but how can we send to that view @R.K.Saini

Comment: Why don't you use simple form. it will send your data to desired controller/view and do redirect as well.

Comment: i can't. bcoz i want to send data of multiple checkbox values. so i have used js function as above mentioned in the question to identify which row has been selected and after that getting the value. after that i want to pass that data to controller.

Comment: So you need to send an array of object containing dc_value and customer_name. You can use a form with hidden field and save your json string to that hidden field and then submit that form to your controller action. Then in php you just need to decode that json string to get your posted data back